# VPN tunnel to home network and then connect to work VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a orange pi pc running armbian and need to make a sort of tunnel.

I need something in case i need to leave the country to be able to connect with my laptop to my home network and then to the work VPN. The work VPN should only see the connection coming from my home VPN

What am i looking for here? Any guides or tips on how i can do this?

The router is a Vodafone station and has port forwarding for IPv6.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create port forwarding rules on the Vodafone router and install a VPN server
on the OrangePi. It can be any VPN: wireguard, OpenVPN, pptp, anything. Install any DDNS client too, so even if the router IP address changes, you will be able to access it.

Install the VPN client on your computer, and configure the VPN connection to be the primary gateway, so every connection will be router to the VPN server. This way, when you connect the work VPN, the connection will be routed to the OrangePi, and from there to your company.

Comment: Hi, thanks
Im gonna go ahead and accept the answer.
Now i have a more specific issue i just cannot get past no matter what i try/check.
Could you lend your expertise perhaps?
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241569/first-time-setup-of-openvpn-cannot-connect-network-is-unreachable-pivpn?fbclid=IwAR0nNC7L-86mu77e1gKcVGU3bthtMdnU7Z3UMGz_852KxazvfwnaFII4XMU
Thanks!